# Do not receive callback from BeginGetResponse

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have trouble following the examples to get the callback.

I have the following code:

```
 private void startWebRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri url = new Uri("http://localhost.com/dummyGet");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);
    }

    private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("Don not get here");
        try
        {
            var req = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            using (var response = req.EndGetResponse(callbackResult))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Code");
            }
        }
        catch
        {  }
    }
```

I have been bangin my head against this all day, I can see the get request in my browser, or with client in fiddler/wireshark. But the code (ReadWebRequestCallback) does not get called.

Edit:
Also note that if I use WebClient and DownloadStringAsync it works, but i need other HTTP status codes than 404 and 200.:

```
_client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
_client.DownloadStringAsync(_concurrentCheckUrl);
}

private void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {// Works, gets here}
```

Comment: put a try catch around request.BeginGetResponse and see if some exception raises there

Comment: Does not seem like it raises an exception.

Comment: Considering you swallow any exceptions with an empty `catch{}`, how do you know it doesn't make it into ReadWebRequest?

Comment: Well, I do log a message. Will edit the code to reflect it.

Comment: Did you wait long enough for TimeoutException to happen? (around a minute?) Also your url in sample looks suspicios (localhost.com, no quotes), but assuming it is copy/paste error.

Comment: In chrome developer tools I see the call succeed. So I know that it actually calls and get a success (200). Have not got a TimeoutException. And yes, that was an error, fixed so it is free of syntax error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for all the help!

I ended up with doing this like described in [Simplify Async networking with Tasks in SL5](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/04/simplifying-async-networking-with-tasks-in-silverlight-5) with tasks.

```
HttpWebRequest _request;

private void doGetRequest()
  _request = WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri("http://localhost/getDummy")) as HttpWebRequest;
        var webTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>
            (_request.BeginGetResponse, _request.EndGetResponse, null)
          .ContinueWith(
            task =>
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)task.Result;
                // The reason I use HttpRequest, not WebRequest, to get statuscode.
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
                {
                     //Do Stuff
                }
            });
```

I do however think the problem relied in that my logging did not log when it was in the callback, this I cannot understand. But after banging my head to the wall for a day, I'll leave that behind. But think my actual post would work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the solution, but is the owning thread closed before the callback is called?  Being silverlight I doubt it but I thought I would bring it up.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx - notice the

```
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject (result.AsyncWaitHandle, new WaitOrTimerCallback(TimeoutCallback), myHttpWebRequest, DefaultTimeout, true);

  // The response came in the allowed time. The work processing will happen in the 
  // callback function.
  allDone.WaitOne();
```

That may be what you should try over a Thread.Sleep.  If this isn't the problem, can you confirm the code is never firing by adding a breakpoint or some other output statement just to be safe?

Comment: This is my best guess too. Put the thread to sleep for a few seconds after issuing the call, that is as a last line in startWebRequest(). I mean just to find out whether or not it's a thread issue.

Comment: What should be the expected result? Have added an 30 seconds Thread.Sleep(new Timespan(0,0,30)) now, but the only thing that happens is that the starting of the video is delayed.

Comment: A thread sleep would allow the request to complete it's work, but if the statement directly following the sleep cause an exit, it's not garunteed to fire. Threading is tricky, and Microsoft's new model is definitely pushing to the forefront.  Who calls 'startWebRequest'?

Comment: Now Im actually thinking the problem relies in my logging and that it actually is called. Will give a reply if thats true. But feel its weird if my logging mechanism work before, but not in the callback. I have used both Console.WriteLine, HtmlPage.Window.Eval("message"), and Player.SendLog which uses LogEntry.